Import "pandas_datareader.data" could not be resolved
I am trying to download financial data using the library pandas_datareader
Here is a code that I'm trying to run:
from pandas_datareader import data
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf
yf.pdr_override() 

symbol = 'AMZN'
data_source='google'
start_date = '2010-01-01'
end_date = '2016-01-01'
df = data.get_data_yahoo(symbol, start_date, end_date)
print(df)
df.head()

The error message I got is "Import "pandas_datareader" could not be resolved" and "Import "fix_yahoo_finance" could not be resolved".
I made sure that pandas_datareader is installed and up to date using pip install, but I'm not sure if I installed it to the correct environment.
I'm relatively new to the topic, so any advice or troubleshooting step would be much appreciated!

Could you please provide how are you running your code and how did you verified that pandas_datareader is installed?

I cannot install fix_yahoo_finance package with pip even though I installed yfinance.

After searching a bit, I found following:

fix-yahoo-finance is now renamed to yfinance which you can install with:

pip install yfinance --upgrade --no-cache-dir


Install pandas_datareader with:

pip install pandas-datareader


If you are using Python 3.10+, then you will receive distutils error which can be solved with:

pip install setuptools  


According to the GitHub issue,

yf.pdr_override() is removed already and you will get an error.
